# Xpath for getting unique values of node names

Tags: xml, xpath, unique

I have the following XML:

```
<MyFruits>
   <Apple>A</Apple>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Mango>12</Mango>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Orange>A</Orange>
   <Orange>A</Orange>
   <Orange>A</Orange>
   <Apple>B</Apple>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Mango>12</Mango>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Orange>10</Orange>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Orange>10</Orange>
   <Apple>C</Apple>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Mango>12</Mango>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Orange>10</Orange>
   <Apple>19</Apple>
   <Orange>10</Orange>
</MyFruits>
```

I want to get only unique fruits among them (Apple,Mango and Orange)

Can anyone suggest an XPath to retrieve using XPath 1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this can be done in a single XPath 1.0 expression because it would require two nested levels of predicates with the inner one depending on the value of the outer one, i.e.

```
/MyFruits/*[not(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(node-from-outer-predicate)])]
```

and this isn't possible in XPath 1.0.

It would be trivial in XPath 2.0

```
distinct-values(/MyFruits/*/name())
```